# Graphing Polar equation

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates, curves, algebraic-curves

I was plotting graphs on Desmos, I plotted $r=a+sin(\theta)$ and it rightfully spit out a cardiod at $a=-1$ and $a=1$

Then when I was sliding the values of $a$,  it spits out a limacon for $-1<a<1$($a\neq0$)

Then I notice a weird thing that is when I was sliding the value between $1<|a|<3$ it was spitting out something between cardiod and a circle. What is it called?

For values $|a|>3$ it was mapping circles. Why does this back and forth happen between circles, limacons, cardiodes and the unknown shape?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I had to ask for the term because I can't keep referring to it as unknown shape. So, term is a cheeky question there. The profound one is the base of the post

Comment: A circle is $r=a$, hence your curve is not one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, the two answers have cleared my doubts. However, $r=asin(\theta)+bcos(\theta)$ can also be a circle.

Comment: @Rifat: that's right, but through the origin rather than centered on the origin.

Answer (score 3):

The figure is called a limaçon for all $a \neq 0$, *in particular* it's called a cardioid for $|a|=1$. In general, the polar equation $r = a + b\sin\theta$ produces a limaçon when $a,b \neq 0$, and a cardioid when $|a/b|=1$.

What it *doesn't* produce is circles. Remembering $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $r\sin\theta = y$, we find
$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2 = r(a + \sin \theta) = a \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + y $$
and thus
$$(x^2 + y^2-y)^2 = a^2(x^2 + y^2) $$
which is the Cartesian equation of a quartic curve for all $a \neq 0$ (for $a=0$ it does simplify to a degree 2 equation, specifically that of a circle, but you're excluding that case). It would however describe a proper circle for all $a \neq 0$ if the $-y$ term on the LHS weren't there.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was looking so close to a circle, so I kind of thought it would be, but now I checked, the chords aren't always the same length from the same distance from the center

Answer (score 3):

In fact, *all* of these graphs are [limaçons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on). The generic equation for a limaçon in polar coordinates is $r = a + b \cos (\theta)$ for a limaçon oriented horizontally, along the $x$-axis, or $r = a + b \sin(\theta)$ for a limaçon oriented vertically, along the $y$-axis. There are different types of limaçons, depending on the relationship between $a$ and $b$ in the polar equation.

1. If $a < b$ then you will have a ***looped*** limaçon
2. If $a = b$ then you will have a ***cardioid***. A cardioid is actually a type of limaçon, i.e. the only limaçon that has a cusp.
3. If $b < a < 2b$ then you will have a ***dimpled*** limaçon. This is the "weird thing" you noticed when you had the slider in the range roughly between $1$ and $3$.
4. If $a \ge 2b$ then you will actually have a ***convex*** limaçon. At exactly $a=2b$, the dimple will flatten out, and if $a > 2b$, then it will even start to bow outwards again... however, it is still **not a circle**! As $a \gg 2b$, the difference between the limaçon and a circle is hardly discernible, but it is there.

You can tell that your limaçon is not a circle, by plotting an actual circle with similar parameters ([Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2szhwsw0xd)), and (1) noticing the difference between the two equations, and (2) noticing the visual difference on a graph. Move the sliders for $a$ and $b$ to scale the limaçon. See how, for $a \ge 2b$, it looks quite circle*ish*, but remains very slightly "fatter" along the horizontal direction than a true circle.

Comparing the polar-form equations gives more insight into why exactly this happens.

Before we get into that, however, I'll just take a brief detour and show the derivation for the circle equation in the first place. I simply started with the Cartesian equation for a circle of radius $a$ centered at $(0, b)$, and converted to polar coordinates. (EDIT: this derivation is only for the inscribed circle; I have added also the circle circumscribed about the limaçon to the Desmos graph, but I will not show the derivation of that circle here.)
\begin{align}
  x^2 + (y-b)^2 &= a^2 \\
  x^2 + y^2 - 2by + b^2 &= a^2 \\
  r^2 - 2br\sin(\theta) &= a^2 - b^2 \\
  r^2 - 2br\sin(\theta) + b^2\sin^2(\theta) &= a^2 - b^2 + b^2\sin^2(\theta) \\
 (r - b\sin(\theta))^2 &= a^2 - b^2(1 - \sin^2(\theta)) \\
  r &= b\sin(\theta) + \sqrt{a^2 - b^2\cos^2(\theta)}
\end{align}

OK, now that that's out of the way - let $r(\theta)$ be the limaçon, and let $\hat{r}(\theta)$ be the circle (the equation we just found a moment ago), as polar functions of $\theta$. To make the difference between them crystal clear, we can do a little convenient rearranging, and write both equations in terms of the ratio $a/b$, so that as $a/b\to\infty$, the limaçon gets closer to the circle.

First, the limaçon:
\begin{align}
  r(\theta) &= a + b\sin(\theta)  \\
      &= b\left( \sin(\theta) + \frac{a}{b} \right)  \\
\end{align}

And second, the circle:
\begin{align}
  \hat{r}(\theta) &= b\sin(\theta) + \sqrt{a^2 - b^2\cos^2(\theta)}  \\
      &= b\left( \sin(\theta) + \sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2 - \cos^2(\theta)} \right)  \\
      &\approx b\left( \sin(\theta) + \sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2} \right)  \text{ if }a\gg b \\
      &\approx b\left( \sin(\theta) + \frac{a}{b} \right) = r(\theta)
\end{align}

As $a$ becomes very much larger than $b$, the ratio $a/b\to\infty$. On the other hand $-\cos^2(\theta)$ will never be less than $-1$ or greater than $0$. So for $a\gg b$, this term becomes essentially insignificant; it is "dwarfed" by the enormous $a/b$ term under the square root. This term, which is tiny for $a\gg b$, is where the difference between your almost-circle limaçon & a true circle enters in.

Comment: Wow! I couldn't thank enough. This clears each and every doubt I had. So structured and beautifully classified and written. And the desmos link is just amazing.

Comment: @Rifat Thank you kindly sir :) I am glad to have been of help! If you are interested, I have made one small tweak to the Desmos graph. The old version only had the inscribed circle - the one that just touches the inside of the limaçon. This was because the equation of the inscribed circle was the easiest to think of and explain in my answer. Now I added the circumscribed circle as well - the one that just touches the *outside* of the limaçon. If $b=1$ and $a\ge 3$, then the difference in their radii will be less than $5\%$.